# $(this) not "refreshing" with $(document).on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JavaScript (or jQuery) and I can't retrieve correctly the id of the button calling the event.

Here is a simplified example :
I have 2 buttons with the same class (the class is used for the listener) with id "button_1" and "button_2", I'll click on one of them, launch the event and get the correct id. Now, I'll click on the other button, launch the event and I still get the id of the first button.

Here is the code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.list-button' , function(e){
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var button_id = target.id;
    alert(button_id);
}
```

or with jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click', '.list-button' , function(e){
    var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(button_id);
}
```

Both output only the first event caller. The second time, it'll launch the function but it's like " $(this) " is still the first event caller.

EDIT : I simplified too much my example, the alert is working fine and it was crashing later in the code. It was linked to wordpress and I had to undefine the variable to correct it. Thanks for your help even if my request was exceptionnaly useless, I guess you helped me to step back and reading step by step.

Comment: A question asking for code help must always include a [mcve]. Post your HTML please.

Comment: Seems like something isn't working on my side, it's giving me headache.

Comment: @Gio The issue lies in your HTML. Try to give us a code that doesn't work, and we'll try our best to help you.

Comment: Break your code down. Start with a blank HTML page with just the minimum amount of code, two buttons, jQuery and the JavaScript to produce the alerts. Once that's working start adding more content until it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.list-button', function(e) {
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(button_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="list-button" id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="list-button" id="button2">Button 2</button>
```

Make sure you check your HTML to have it right.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working fine !

```js
$(document).on('click', '.list-button', function(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var button_id = target.id;
  alert(button_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="list-button" id="button_1">Button 1</button>
<button class="list-button" id="button_2">Button 2</button>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar Argh 20 seconds quicker

Comment: LoL. Ha ha... Looks mysterious.

Comment: Fine, you have used the second model... Good.